# Flutter - can't see validation messages for disabled form fields

Tags: validation, input, flutter

For my `Flutter` App, I'm using many input form fields for data input, and assigning a validation method for each, for all fields the error message appears normally, just below the field, except for one field that takes value from a picker dialog, so that i made it disabled (`enabled=false`) to prevent user input on it

Is it normal that a disabled field doesn't show validation error messages? if yes, should i do something different to prevent user input on that field other than making it disabled?

Answer (score 37):

Simply add an `InputDecoration` with an `errorStyle` to the `TextFormField` to use any color you want for the error, which applies for both enabled and disabled fields:

```
TextFormField(
  ...
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    errorStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Theme.of(context).errorColor, // or any other color
    ),
  ),
 ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the very clean solution @Ovidiu :)

Comment: This answer is kind of a miracle #Kudos